# BeforeTreeItemSelectionChanged event in JavaFX TreeView?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

In JavaFX TreeView, is there an event similar to "BeforeTreeItemSelectionChanged"? I would like to save some settings on the old TreeItem before a new TreeItem is clicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to have a reference to the previously selected item you can add a [`ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) to listen to the change of the [`selectedItemProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) of the selection model of the `TreeView` as it's [`changed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html#changed%28javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue,%20T,%20T%29) method passes the previous value for you:

`changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue)`

This example prints the value of the previously selected item on selection:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if(oldVal != null)
        System.out.println(oldVal.getValue());
});
```

And this is the same, but using anonymous class to see the types:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<String>> observable, TreeItem<String> oldValue, TreeItem<String> newValue) {
        if(oldValue != null)
            System.out.println(oldValue.getValue());
    }
});
```